# paso valores a mi textArea y me lo pasa con etiquetas HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

cuando paso los valores me muestra con las etiquetas de HTML cualquier texto que escribo
GRACIAS de antemano

backend

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textArea1.InnerText))
        {
            Texto1.InnerText = textArea1.InnerText;
            lblTest.Text = textArea1.InnerText;
            TextBox1.Text = textArea1.InnerText;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     string aa =   ex.Message;
        lblTest.Text = aa;
    }
```

frontend

```
    <div class="adjoined-bottom">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-width-100">

                <textarea  id="textArea1" name="editor" runat="server" class="ckeditor">

               </textarea>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

editor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    initSample();
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Pasar Email" OnClick="Button1_Click" /> 
<br />
<br />
<br />

<textarea  id="Texto1" rows="10" runat="server"></textarea>
<br />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<br />

<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<br />

<br />
```

Comment: Al parecer estás usando un estilo editor class="ckeditor" que me imagino te permite poner estilos al texto, ese es tu problema, si deseas texto sin estilos, quita esa referencia.

Comment: exactamente es lo que quiero, que del editor de texto me pase los valores al textArea sin las etiquetas html

Comment: Te recomiendo retirar el editor y dejar la pura caja de texto si el estilo html no te sirve para nada es la solución más fácil

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sería tratar el texto con una expresión regular:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textArea1.InnerHtml))
{
    string plainText = Regex.Replace(textArea1.InnerHtml, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
    Texto1.InnerText = plainText;
    lblTest.Text = plainText;
    TextBox1.Text = plainText;
}
```